# is it possible to change column data every time a new raw label added? automatically in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to make metatitle automatically using title of the post + text (title+text=metatitle)

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET metatitle = concat(title , 'text')
```

is it possible to change metatitle data every time a new raw label added? automatically in phpmyadmin?

I don't have skill to make modification on script

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya MySQL version is 5.6.41

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL version is 5.7 and above, you can use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

For, that you will have to `Alter` the column as:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY metatitle VARCHAR(255) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(title,'text'));
```

Comment: i receive this error message
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: @ZiedBM please read my answer; it works only when MySQL version is 5.7 and above; however yours is 5.6 ; You should upgrade the version and try again.